# Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, proxychains

I keep getting this error Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it," when trying to run proxychains in Ubuntus 22.04. The command below did not work and I have updated, there seems to be no fix on this anywhere on the web not even on ubuntu forum. Please help.

sudo snap refresh snapd-desktop-integration --stable

sudo snap refresh snapd-desktop-integration --stable  and sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
I was expecting proxychains to work.